# Regular and irregular singular points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

the differential equation
$$(x+4)(16-x^2)y'' + 2xy' - (x-4)y = 0$$

I find that $x=4$ and $x=-4$ are singular points and the rest are ordinary .
Additionally, I find them irregular singular points. Is that right?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: It is not correct. One of them is regular singular.

Comment: Why would you say one of them is regular ? It equals with        (x+4)^2•(x-4)^2 y” -2(x-4)x y + (x-4)^2y. If for example 4 is regular, shouldn’t (x-4)^2 disappear from the third term?